# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long, merging net cdf files

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to merge two netcdf files, I get this error when I try to merge them. I have posted my code below.

```
import xarray as xr
path1 = 'C:/Users/quincoug/Desktop/Quinn Code/CMIP6/6/US/ssp585/mrro_day_MRI-ESM2- 
0_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19991231.nc'
path2 = 'C:/Users/quincoug/Desktop/Quinn Code/CMIP6/6/US/ssp585/mrro_day_MRI-ESM2- 
0_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_20000101-20141231.nc'

HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=False

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(path1)
ds.to_netcdf()
ds2 = xr.open_mfdataset(path2)
ds2.to_netcdf()


dsmerge = xr.merge([ds,ds2])

new_filename_2 = 'C:\\Users\\quincoug\\Desktop\\Quinn Code\\CMIP6\\6\\US\\ssp585\\USHistory.nc'
print ('saving to ', new_filename_2)
dsmerge.to_netcdf(path=new_filename_2)
dsmerge.close()
print ('finished saving')
print(new_filename_2)
```

Comment: Please tidy up the question. The title should be a qustion, not an error message. What code is actually throwing the error? Is it the print statement at the end? I'm confused here.